# Transparent button on top of images

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a transparent button on top of a images.

Like this

[image]

My css skills hit the limit here. How do I do this i css? It should work on all browsers.

Comment: Well, I don’t know where to start, so I start here. If that’s not okay, what is the purpose with this site then?

Comment: You don't START with Stack Overflow...you come to Stack Overflow LAST.

Comment: I have tried it out, but no working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have a div container there inside is the image tag and underneath the button tag.

```
<div id="box">
<img....>
<div class="overlaybutton"><a href=...." class="button"><font color="#ffffff">profile blabla</font></a></div>
</div>
```

This should be the minimum code you should provide I assume.
Now to handle your problem:
All you need to do is change the position of box img and overlaybutton in your css code. Something like this:

```
.box img {
  position: absolute;
..
..
}

.box .overlaybutton {
  position: absolute;
  opacity:0.5;  //to make it transparent
}
```

The rest should be self explained. Hope this helped you.

Comment: I try this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a bad solution, and how do I optimize this to work properly?
The margin-top: -37px; and margin-left: -83px; is not the right way, and this don’t work across platform.

HTML:

```
<div class="transparent-button-box">
<div ng-if="(!model.fileList)">
       <img ng-src="{{dummyimgpath}}" class="profile-img-box" width="{{imgwidthlarge}}" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div ng-if="(model.fileList.length > 0)">
       <div ng-repeat="fileList in model.fileList">
          <a prettyp class="image" ng-href="{{fileList.uri}}" rel="prettyPhoto[mainpair1]" target="_blank" >
             <img ng-src="{{fileList.uri}}" class="profile-img-box" width="{{imgwidthlarge}}" alt="" />
          </a>
       </div>
    </div>
    <a class="overlaybutton" href="" data-ng-click="showUploadPic()">Upload img</a>
```

CSS:

```
.transparent-button-box {
position: relative;}

.transparent-button-box .overlaybutton {
position: absolute;
background-color: #000;
color: #fff;
opacity: 0.7;
filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
height: 33px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
margin-top: -37px;
margin-left: -83px;
width: 167px;}
```

Comment: The transparent-button-box is nested inside another div. Then it all shows up bad, when I change it to position: absolute.